# How to analyse count data

Tags: interpretation, count-data, poisson-regression

I have count data on bird abundance obtained from 12 locations. I have summed the abundance for each site as I have been sampling each location twice and there is no significant difference between them (I used the Wilcoxon rank-sum test). The next variable I have is the percentage of the urban landscape at each location. I want to know whether the amount of urban landscape influences abundance. I have looked into Poisson regression, but I am new to stats and I am not sure if that is the correct test, nor how to interpret its results.

Comment: Wilcoxon comes up often when you Google "tests for non-normal data". But if the data aren't normal, what are they? Ignoring structure completely is rarely a good idea. Wilcoxon's results are hard to interpret. it's only a test of means when distributions are symmetric - counts are often heavily skewed, and so if not a test of means what is it? 
That's asked somewhat rhetorically - it's a mean *rank* difference - but honestly what would one do with that kind of information?

Answer (score 6):

- Poisson regression sounds fine
- summing the abundance is fine, but I wouldn't use a Wilcoxon test to decide whether or not to do it; I would decide *a priori* whether or not I was interested in within-site variation over time, or whether there were covariates that changed over time within sites that I wanted to account for (if you don't aggregate, then you probably need to use a mixed model with a random effect of site)
- in R (for example) you would use `fitted_model <- glm(count ~ urban, data = ..., family = poisson)` to run the Poisson model. `anova(fitted_model)` and the coefficient estimate in `summary(fitted_model)` will give you p-values for the effect of urban landscape (they're slightly different tests, the `anova()` result is slightly more reliable).
- technically both of those tests assume you have a large data set (12 is not particularly large), so you *might* want to use bootstrapping or a permutation test to double-check whether your results are robust
- you should **definitely** check for overdispersion/consider whether a negative binomial [`MASS::glm.nb`] (or quasi-Poisson [`family = "quasipoisson"`]) rather than a Poisson regression is appropriate (you might want to *assume* that you have overdispersion)
- the coefficient for `urban` gives the expected increase in the *natural logarithm* of the number of counts for a one-unit increase in the proportion of urban landscape. If the coefficient is small, it can be interpreted as approximately a proportional change.
- the `DHARMa` and `performance::check_model()` packages/functions are very useful for diagnostic checks.

Comment: Would you advise quasipoisson over poisson to account for the possibly uneven denominators (for instance, how is % urban defined, are all sampled locations really alike even if the same sq. kms, etc.)?

Comment: We didn't get much information. If the sampling effort/area/etc. is different for different sites that would typically be handled by adding an `offset(log(effort))` term to the model (to make the response effectively "counts per unit effort"). Negative binomial and quasi-Poisson approaches handle the same problem (overdispersion - one source would be additional unmeasured variation, but if you *know* the variation is from sampling effort it's better to include it directly).

Comment: `family = quasipoisson` makes some things (like checking model fit via LRT rather than Wald test) awkward

Comment: But we favor quasiX methods precisely because they're a bit robust to those usual model-based assessments, and of course they don't prevent you from using simple box plots, smoothers, and scatterplots, to basically assess distributions and trends.

Comment: I'm just saying there are tradeoffs.